# Super simple CSS tooltip in a table, why is it not displaying and can I make it work?

Tags: html, css, html-table, tooltip

I have been trying to implement many different tooltips on this page for my client, he's adamant that we have a picture of the product show up when you hover over the product name in the order page. I decided to use the super simple CSS tooltip, it's very easy to implement and does exactly what we want. It works on a dynamic page, the others I tried didn't.

I have made an example here: [CSS tooltip in table example](http://jsfiddle.net/WNzhJ/).<-- *updated to remove errors*.

**HTML:**

```
<table class="mytable" id="cart">

  <tr id="titles">
    <th id="varekodetext">Varekode</th>
    <th id="produkttext">Produkt</th>
    <th id="pristext">Pris</th>
    <th id="emptee">&nbsp;</th>
    <th id="antalltext">Antall</th>
    <th id="pristotaltext">Pris Total</th>
    <th id="sletttext">Slett</th>
  </tr>
  <tbody>
    <tr class="even first" id="topborder" height="40px">
      <td class="cart2Varekode"> <span>39261-02 </span>
      </td>
      <td class="cart2Produkt"> <a href="/Plantronics-CS361N.11" target="_blank" class="tooltip" title="Plantronics CS361N"> 
                Plantronics CS361N
                <span> 
                    <img src="http://www.euroworker.no/public/upload/productimage/220-353-2.jpg" alt="Plantronics CS361N" /> 

                </span> 
                </a>
        <p>
        </p>
      </td>
      <td class="cart2Price">
        <span class="actualPrice">2390.-</span>
      </td>
      <td class="cart2Salg">
        <span class="orderlistPrice"></span>
      </td>
      <td class="antallbox">
        <span class="cartQuant"><input name="item_1363" class="DG-spinner" id="text" type="text" value="1"/> <span class="cartUpdate"><button type="submit" class="submit" id="rfrsh_btn" name="saveFields" title="Oppdater" value="">&nbsp;</button></span>
        </span>
      </td>
      <td class="cart2Total">
        <span class="basePrice">2390.-</span><span class="actualPrice">2390.-</span>
      </td>
      <td class="delete">
        <a class="slett" href="../..//order/delete/1363?return=" title="Slett">Remove</a>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="odd last" id="topborder" height="40px">
      <td class="cart2Varekode"> <span>7050-20</span>
      </td>
      <td class="cart2Produkt"> <a href="/Target-7050CC-Duo-UNC.7" target="_blank" class="tooltip" title="Target 7050CC Duo UNC">Target 7050CC Duo UNC<span>
      <img src="upload/productimage/7-250-2.jpg?1251022192" alt="Target 7050CC Duo UNC" />               
                </span> 
                </a>

        <p>
          <div class="productOptions" style="color:#b2b2b2;">

            <div class="nonEditableOption">
              Skal tilkobles: Alcatel IP Touch
            </div>

            <div class="productOptionsMenu">
              <a style="color:#6c8aa2;" href="/order/options/1377" ajax="/order/optionForm/1377">Endre valg</a>
            </div>
          </div>

        </p>

      </td>
      <td class="cart2Price"><span class="actualPrice">899.-</span>
      </td>
      <td class="cart2Salg">
        <span class="salg" title="Rabatt">&nbsp;</span>

        <span class="orderlistPrice" title="Opprinnelige prisen"> 
                    (1599.-)
                </span>
      </td>
      <td class="antallbox">
        <span class="cartQuant"><input name="item_1377" class="DG-spinner" id="text" type="text" value="1"/> 

                    <span class="cartUpdate"><button type="submit" class="submit" id="rfrsh_btn" name="saveFields" title="Oppdater" value="">&nbsp;</button></span>
        </span>
      </td>


      <td class="cart2Total">

        <span class="basePrice">899.-</span><span class="actualPrice">899.-</span>

      </td>
      <td class="delete">

        <a class="slett" href="../..//order/delete/1377?return=" title="Slett">Remove</a>

      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="6" class="cols-six"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="topborder-tr">
      <td class="subTotalCaption2">&nbsp;</td>
      <td colspan="4" class="subTotalCaption2">Mva (25%):</td>
      <td class="amount taxAmount2">822.-</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>



    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="subTotalCaption2">&nbsp;</td>
      <td colspan="4" class="subTotalCaption2">Totalt:</td>
      <td class="subTotal2">4111.-</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>

    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="5"></td>
      <td class="cartQuant"></td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="7">
        <a href="/" class="continueShopping"><span>&nbsp;</span></a>
        <div class="checkoutButtons">
          <a href="/checkout" class="proceedToCheckout" onclick="return Order.submitCartForm(this);"><span>&nbsp;</span></a>

        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      new Order.OptionLoader($('cart'));

    </script>

  </tbody>

</table>
```

**CSS:**

```
.cart2Produkt a:hover {
  background: #ffffff;
  text-decoration: none;
  z-index: 999;
}

/*BG color is a must for IE6*/

.tooltip {
  text-align: left;
}

.cart2Produkt a.tooltip span {
  z-index: 999;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  left: -999px;
  opacity: 0;
  padding: 2px 3px;
  margin-left: 8px;
  width: 130px;
  -webkit-transition: opacity;
  -webkit-transition-timing-function: ease-in;
  -webkit-transition-duration: 500ms;
}

.cart2Produkt a.tooltip:hover span {
  z-index: 999;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  right: 50%;
  opacity: 1;
  background: #ffffff;
  border: 1px solid #cccccc;
  color: #6c6c6c;
  top: -35px;
  left: -15px;
  z-index: 10;
  border-radius: 5px;
  -moz-border-radius: 5px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  padding: 1px;
  -webkit-transition: opacity;
  -webkit-transition-timing-function: ease-out;
  -webkit-transition-duration: 500ms;
}


/**************IGNORE BELOW*************/

#topborder {
  /*border-top: 1px #ccc solid;*/
  padding-bottom: 10px;
}

#topborder-tr {
  border-top: 1px #ccc solid;
}

.mytable {
  width: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.mytable,
.mytable th,
.mytable tr,
.mytable td {
  border: 0;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
}

.mytableborders,
.mytableborders th,
.mytableborders tr,
.mytableborders td {
  border: 1px #ccc solid;
  /*width:670px;*/
}

.mytable td,
.mytable td span {
  padding-bottom: 0;
  padding-top: 5px;
  /*border-top: 1px #ccc solid;*/
  vertical-align: middle;
  font-size: 12px;
}

.mytable th {
  vertical-align: bottom;
  height: 30px;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
}

#titles {
  margin: 0px auto 0px auto;
  width: 100%;
  padding-bottom: 50px;
  z-index: 1;
  border: 1px #ccc solid;
  border-left: none;
  border-right: none;
}

.cart2Produkt a {
  color: #0a5692;
  text-decoration: none;
  line-height: 15px;
  clear: both;
  z-index: 999;
}

productOptionsMenu {
  clear: both;
}

#pristotaltext p,
#varekodetext p,
#sletttext p,
#pristext p,
#antalltext p,
#produkttext p {
  font: 12px/11px "Helvetica";
  margin: 0px;
  color: #828273;
  text-align: left;
}

#thinline,
#thinlinecopy {
  background: url(../../upload/thinline.png) no-repeat;
  visibility: visible;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0px;
  z-index: 4;
  width: 747px;
  height: 1px;
}

#thinlinefakt {
  background: url(../../upload/thinline.png) no-repeat;
  visibility: visible;
  position: absolute;
  top: 100px;
  left: 0px;
  z-index: 4;
  width: 747px;
  height: 1px;
}

#thinlinefakt2 {
  background: url(../../upload/thinline.png) no-repeat;
  background-position: bottom;
  visibility: visible;
  position: absolute;
  top: 205px;
  left: 0px;
  z-index: 4;
  width: 747px;
  height: 28px;
  margin: 5px;
  margin-left: 10px;
  margin-top: 0px;
  padding: 5px;
  color: #000000;
  font-size: 22px;
  font-family: "Helvetica";
}

.Fadresse {
  display: block;
  margin: 5px;
  padding: 0;
  color: #000000;
  font-size: 22px;
  font-family: "Helvetica";
}

#thinlinecopylever {
  background: url(../../upload/thinline.png) no-repeat;
  background-repeat: repeat-x;
  position: relative;
  left: 0px;
  top: -3px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 1px;
  padding: 0px;
}

#varekodetext {
  width: 65px;
  padding-left: 5px;
  text-align: center;
}

#produkttext {
  width: 150px;
}


/*#sgproductview  {

margin: 0px auto 0px auto;
width: 595px;
height:1%;
z-index:1;
}*/

#thinlinecopy {
  top: 1px;
}

#antalltext {
  width: 25px;
  text-align: center;
}

#pristotaltext {
  width: 10%;
  text-align: right;
}

#sletttext {
  width: 10%;
  text-align: center;
}

#thinline {
  top: 19px;
  position: absolute;
}

#pristext {
  width: 24px;
  text-align: center;
}

#emptee {
  background-color: none;
  width: 40px;
}


/*****************************************CONTENT*/

.cart2Produkt p,
.cart2Varekode p,
.cart2Salg p {
  font: 13px/11px "Helvetica";
  margin: 0px;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  text-align: left;
}

.cart2Produkt p a {
  color: #000000;
}

.cart2Total p {
  font: 13px/11px "Helvetica";
  margin: 0px;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  text-align: left;
  color: #000000;
}

.cart2Varekode {
  visibility: visible;
  z-index: 2;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: top;
  padding-top: 3px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.cart2Produkt {
  visibility: visible;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-align: left;
  position: relative;
  width: 28%;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding-bottom: 2px;
}

.cart2Produkt a {
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.cart2Price {
  visibility: visible;
  z-index: 2;
  text-align: right;
  width: 6%;
  position: relative;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.cart2Price p {
  font: 13px/11px "Helvetica";
  margin: 0px;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  text-align: right;
  width: 80%;
}

.cart2Total p {
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: right;
}

.cart2Salg p {
  color: #B2B2B2;
  width: 20%;
}

.cart2Total {
  visibility: visible;
  z-index: 2;
  text-align: right;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.antallbox {
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-align: center;
}

.antallbox input {
  text-align: right;
  outline: none;
  width: 30px;
}

.antallbox input:focus {
  text-align: right;
  outline: none;
  border: 1px #000 solid;
  background-color: #F0F7FD;
}

.cartQuant {
  width: 30px;
  /*    white-space: nowrap;*/
  text-align: left;
  margin-top: 5px;
}

.cart2Salg {
  visibility: visible;
  z-index: 2;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.orderlistPrice {
  text-decoration: line-through;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #b2b2b2;
  font-size: 12px;
}

.salg {
  background: url(../../upload/salg.png) no-repeat;
  visibility: visible;
  z-index: 2;
  width: 28px;
  height: 24px;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}

.delete {
  visibility: visible;
  z-index: 2;
  height: 21px;
  background: none;
  text-align: center;
}

.slett {
  width: 24px;
  height: 19px;
  background-image: url(../../upload/delete_box_sprite.png);
  background-position: 0 0;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
}

.slett:hover {
  width: 24px;
  height: 19px;
  background-image: url(../../upload/delete_box_sprite.png);
  background-position: -24px 0;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
}

.productOptions {
  background-color: #fff;
  postion: absolute;
  visibility: visible;
  display: block;
  top: 3px;
  padding-left: 5px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
}

.nonEditableOption {
  background-color: #fff;
  float: left;
  postion: absolute;
  margin-right: 10px;
  visibility: visible;
  display: block;
}
```

This page used to be displayed using divs, I have since changed it to a table, as it's tabular data and easier to work with. It worked fine when it used divs, now it's in a table, it won't display the span on hover.

My questions are:

1. Why is it not working?
2. How can I make it work?
3. If not, does anyone
       know another super easy to implement
       tooltip that can work properly on a
       dynamic page?

Here's the DIV tooltip for reference: [DIV display tooltip](http://jsfiddle.net/waFC8/).

**HTML:**

```
<div id="JSwrap">
    <div id="cart2Produkt">
        <p><a href="/Target-7050-Softphone-USB-Duo.220" target="_blank" class="tooltip" title="Target 7050 Softphone USB Duo ">Target 7050 Softphone USB Duo
    <span><img src="http://www.euroworker.no/public/upload/productimage/220-353-2.jpg?1251413379" alt="Target 7050 Softphone USB Duo " />
<br /> 
  </span> 
</a>
        </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
#JSwrap {
  /*for jsfiddle only*/
  position: absolute;
  left: 100px;
  top: 50px;
}

#cart2Produkt {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  width: 500px;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 10px;
}

#cart2Produkt a.tooltip span {
  z-index: 999;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  left: -999px;
  opacity: 0;
  padding: 2px 3px;
  margin-left: 8px;
  width: 130px;
  -webkit-transition: opacity;
  -webkit-transition-timing-function: ease-in;
  -webkit-transition-duration: 500ms;
}

#cart2Produkt a.tooltip:hover span {
  z-index: 999;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  right: 50%;
  opacity: 1;
  background: #ffffff;
  border: 1px solid #cccccc;
  color: #6c6c6c;
  top: -35px;
  left: -15px;
  z-index: 10;
  border-radius: 5px;
  -moz-border-radius: 5px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  padding: 1px;
  -webkit-transition: opacity;
  -webkit-transition-timing-function: ease-out;
  -webkit-transition-duration: 500ms;
}

#cart2Produkt img {
  z-index: 999;
}
```

**Edit**: Just noticed it  half works in IE8.

**Update:** It's now working in all browsers, thanks to Daniel pointing out my CSS errors, but is there a way to make it display outside of the table cell?

Comment: If you display the span as block, so making it always visible, does the image appear? (I couldn't get it to)

Comment: It is already set to block, I tried `inline-block` also, this didn't work..

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Find a more readable working solution [here](http://jsfiddle.net/n9GdP/1/):

```css
.cart { width: 100%; }

.hasTooltip span {
    display: none;
    color: #000;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 3px;
}

.hasTooltip:hover span {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #FFF;
    border: 1px solid #CCC;
    margin: 2px 10px;
}
```

```html
<table class="cart"> 
    <tr> 
        <th id="pos">Pos</th> 
        <th id="name">Product</th> 
        <th id="price">Price</th> 
    </tr> 
    <tbody> 
        <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>
                <a href="productdetails.htm" class="hasTooltip">Flatscreen 
                    <span>New visual experience!</span>
                </a>
            </td>
            <td>19.99</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>
                <a href="productdetails.htm" class="hasTooltip">Headset 
                    <span>Inject music directly into your ears!</span>
                </a>
            </td>
            <td>19.99</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody> 
</table>
```

Comment: Very helpful! much more simple than my version :) +1

Comment: I added this to my site, works the same as my previous version, only displays the span within the confines of the table cell.. Is there a way to override this? Have it working here: http://jsfiddle.net/Mcv7P/
Just not in my actual site..

Comment: Your css holds many `z-index` definitions. Clear them up or add `z-index:99999;` to the class `.hasTooltip span { ... }` to work around this problem. Another cause for your problem might be different `display: ...` values overriding each other. Put both css-classes from my example for the tooltip to the bottom of your css definitions or add `!import` to these attributes.

Comment: Ok, got it working, changed the position of cart2Produkt to absolute and hasTooltip to relative. This produced another problem though...

Comment: This only works if you do not have a scrollable page. I have a long table with data. The tooltips I use on some columns. The more you scroll down the page the more messed up gets the calculation of the placement of the tooltip. At some point it is out of view port.

Answer (score 2):

You seem to have a problem with CSS. Simply using styles of the working JSFiddle demo should fix it. You had the span set as `display:none`, however it looks like this tooltip works by hiding the image from the screen, using `left:-999px`.

Check this: http://jsfiddle.net/WNzhJ/

Comment: Thanks Damiel, I did try to make the styles the same.

Comment: decent example but a little complicated.

Answer (score 1):

I have checked your code, and as you can see by the jsfiddle sytax hightlighting there are a lot of errors in your code: for example the span you who starts in your a finishes outside your a. The CSS should work like this. There are a few more errors. i think if you correct them its gonna work. (simply pass the w3c check, then anything should be just fine)

edit: i missed a thing your link should be position: relative; because your tooltip is position: absolute, the absolute always is relative to the last relative parent.

also remove the opacity: 0 in your original span

Comment: Change the positoning, still not working. Still half works in IE8, it displays the hidden span but only within the bounds of the table cell.

Comment: look it works: http://jsfiddle.net/dbZTK/6/ you had a opacity: 0 in your original span (it works in IE because ie does not support CSS opacity, i uses his own crap ;P )

Answer (score 1):

I was trying the same thing, trying to get a CSS tooltip to appear outside of the table cell.  In my case the table cell was only 1px wide so it HAD to show up outside.  I found out that by making the `:hover span` `position: absolute;` and then adding `margin: -37px 0px 0px -50px;` I could use that to move the tooltip around.  BUT!  If I tried to adjust the top/left/bottom/right then the absolute setting positioned it absolutely on the screen, not relative to the cell.

Hope this helps someone.

Comment: thank you I could not figure out how to move it when position: absolute!