# How can I fix the position of tooltips within a scrolling <div>?

Tags: html, css

I'm having some trouble with the positioning of tooltips on a column of data within a table, which itself is inside a vertical scrolling div. A little background for you...

Due to legacy issues which are beyond my control, the page I am developing has to be displayed through an iframe of fixed width and height. The data I need to display has about 12 columns, all of which are required to be displayed. One column will contain serial numbers, which sometimes end up overflowing the bounds of the cell. I've set the overflow of this column to show an ellipsis, and have added tooltips as described in the accepted answer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2736021) question.

When the tooltips are added, it appears to take the distance from the top of the table to the hovered cell, and draw the tooltip that distance from the top of the parent div. This means that, when you scroll down through the div, the tooltips end up being drawn down below the bottom of the div.

I've created a jsFiddle which demonstrates this: http://jsfiddle.net/kuzxLwxe/4/

Here's my css:

```
.ResultsWrapper {
    width:150px;
    height:314px;
    text-align:center;
    overflow-x:hidden;
    overflow-y:scroll;
    border:1px solid black;
}
.ResultsTable {
    width:86px;
    border-collapse:collapse;
    table-layout:fixed;
}
.ResultsTable th, .ResultsTable td {
    border:1px solid black;
    overflow:hidden;
    text-overflow:ellipsis;
}
.ColumnSerialNo {
   width:81px;
}
.hasTooltip span {
    display: none;
    color: #000;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 3px;
}
.hasTooltip:hover span {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #FFF;
    border: 1px solid #CCC;
    margin: 2px 10px;
}
```

And my html:

```
<div class="ResultsWrapper">
    <table class="ResultsTable">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th class="ColumnSerialNo">Serial Number</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td class="hasTooltip">3119985815206<span>3119985815206</span></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="hasTooltip">5665811486586<span>5665811486586</span></td>
            </tr>
            ...
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

I'm using jQuery for other things within the same page, but so far haven't been able to come up with a solution with it. If you think the best way to fix this is by using JS or jQuery I'd love to see the result!

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Change your HTML markup to take more control on `overflow`:

```
<tr>
    <td class="hasTooltip">
        <div class="SerialNumberContainer">
            <div class="SerialNumber">3119985815206</div>
            <div class="SerialNumberTooltip">3119985815206</div>
        </div>
    </td>
</tr>
```

And in your CSS, remove `overflow` from `td`:

```
.ResultsTable th, .ResultsTable td {
    border:1px solid black;
    /* overflow: hidden; this line should delete */
    text-overflow:ellipsis;
}
```

And new CSS:

```
.SerialNumberContainer {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 10;
}

.SerialNumber {
    width: 80px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.SerialNumberTooltip {
    position: absolute;
    top: 10px;
    left: 2px;
    background-color: #FFF;
    border: 1px solid #CCC;
    display: none;
}

.SerialNumberContainer:hover {
    z-index: 20;
}

.SerialNumberContainer:hover .SerialNumberTooltip {
    display: block;
}
```

[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/kuzxLwxe/5/).

Comment: The tooltip of the last row is cut by the edge of the scroll control.

Answer (score 0):

If the width of ResultsWrapper is smaller than the tooltip length, it's not showing the full text.

Wondering how should I show the full tooltip without increase the ResultsWrapper.

```
.ResultsWrapper {
width:100px;
height:314px;
text-align:center;
overflow-x:hidden;
overflow-y:scroll;
border:1px solid black;
}
```

[JSFiddle Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/s5ytr4zc/6/)